# Flow condition returning false

Tags: power-automate

my action due date field is displayed with this format:
2021-07-04T12:55:19Z
Trying to set up a flow with a condition that if action due is greater than today, update status to Late.
How can i set the condition:
using UTC() but this is returning false.
any ideas [image: flow image]

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce your issue, it worked for me. I would suggest printing date field's value along with utcNow() in [Compose] actions to see the difference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]